# Clustering connected set of points (longitude,latitude) using R

Tags: r, google-maps, latitude-longitude

I am working with centered  longitude (x) and  latitude(y) data. My goal is to clustering the connected locations.

Two location on earth (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) are said to be connected if earth_distance((x1,y1),(x2,y2))<15 kilometer.

I am using the distHaversine function in R, to calculate earth distance.

Here is some sample data,

> x=c(1.000000, 1.055672, 1.038712, 1.094459, 1.133179, 1.116241, 1.126053, 1.181824 ,1.377892, 5.869881, 5.925270, 5.909721)

and

> y=c(1.333368,1.304790,1.347332,1.318743,1.332676,1.375229,1.572287,1.544174,2.371105,2.337032,2.383415)

also

> distance <- distHaversine(c(x,y))

I wish find the different clusters formed by the different connected set of points (each connected set of points form a cluster).

I looked at [How to cluster points and plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540831/how-to-cluster-points-and-plot) but I could not solved my problem.

Any reference, suggestion or answer will be very much appreciated.

Comment: R doesn't have a `distHaversine` function, but the `geosphere` package does.

Comment: Your sample data doesn't paste into R. What errors are you getting?

Comment: Thanks for attention... Sorry I did some mistake while typing...I edited the sample data...It will work now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this. First make some coordinates:

```
> x=c(1.000000, 1.055672, 1.038712, 1.094459, 1.133179, 1.116241, 1.126053, 1.181824 ,1.377892, 5.869881, 5.925270)
> y=c(1.333368, 1.304790, 1.347332, 1.318743, 1.332676, 1.375229, 1.572287, 1.544174, 2.371105 ,2.337032, 2.383415)
```

Make into a data frame

```
> xy = data.frame(x=x,y=y)
```

Now use `outer` to loop over all pairs of rows and columns to compute a full distance matrix. This does twice as much work as is really necessary since it computes `i` to `j` and `j` to `i` for all `i` and `j`. Anyway, it gets us a distance matrix:

```
> dmat = outer(1:nrow(xy), 1:nrow(xy), function(i,j)distHaversine(xy[i,],xy[j,]))
```

Now we want a connectivity matrix, which is any pair closer than 15,000 metres:

```
> cmat = dmat < 15000
```

Now we use the `igraph` package to build a connectivity graph object:

```
> require(igraph)
> cgraph = graph.adjacency(cmat)
```

You can plot this to see the cluster formation, but note these are not plotted in your x-y space:

```
> plot(cgraph)
```

Now to get the connected clusters:

```
> clusters(cgraph)
$membership
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 4 4

$csize
[1] 6 2 1 2

$no
[1] 4
```

Which you can add to your data frame thus:

```
> xy$cluster = clusters(cgraph)$membership
> xy
          x        y cluster
1  1.000000 1.333368       1
2  1.055672 1.304790       1
3  1.038712 1.347332       1
4  1.094459 1.318743       1
5  1.133179 1.332676       1
6  1.116241 1.375229       1
7  1.126053 1.572287       2
8  1.181824 1.544174       2
9  1.377892 2.371105       3
10 5.869881 2.337032       4
11 5.925270 2.383415       4
```

And plot:

```
> plot(xy$x,xy$y,col=xy$cluster)
```

Comment: It is working nicely...Thanks for such a good illustration and solution.

Comment: Can you tick the tick to accept this as the answer, please!

Comment: Yes,sure..I was just unaware about this process. Anyway, thanks again for your help.