# Clustering with R

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering, euclidean-distance

I have a data.frame, for example:

```
test<-data.frame(matrix(c(1:5,2:6,3:7),nrow=3))

test<-cbind(rbind(exp(test),test),rbind(test,2*test))
test
#          X1         X2        X3        X4        X5 X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
# 1  2.718282  54.598150  20.08554 403.42879  148.4132  1  4  3  6  5
# 2  7.389056 148.413159  54.59815  20.08554  403.4288  2  5  4  3  6
# 3 20.085537   7.389056 148.41316  54.59815 1096.6332  3  2  5  4  7
# 4  1.000000   4.000000   3.00000   6.00000    5.0000  2  8  6 12 10
# 5  2.000000   5.000000   4.00000   3.00000    6.0000  4 10  8  6 12
# 6  3.000000   2.000000   5.00000   4.00000    7.0000  6  4 10  8 14
```

and my distance matrix

```
dist(test)
#             1           2           3           4           5
# 2  471.181726                                                
# 3 1019.716766  714.553473                                    
# 4  425.980071  427.331552 1102.568122                        
# 5  428.325768  426.014214 1101.559808    8.062258            
# 6  427.427492  425.995993 1100.387152   10.000000    8.062258
```

I have my Hierarchical Clustering (`hclust(dist(test))`) and I want to put in a group, for example all the lines which the distance is lower than 10 (here for example it would be 4 and 5 and 6)

But in reality, my data.frame is much bigger than that, and I want to do it automatically.

Comment: It is unclear what you want to achieve.

Comment: Please specify what exactly needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

First: save your hierarchical clustering.

```
tree <- hclust(dist(test), method="complete")
```

Note I chose the `complete` linkage method. You can read more about why and how it works [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540831/how-to-cluster-points-and-plot/26544427#26544427)

Second: cut the tree at the wanted height (in your case this is 10):

```
cutree(tree, h=10)
# 1 2 3 4 5 6
# 1 2 3 4 4 4
```

As you can see this returns a vector of clusters. In this case `4,5,6` all are in the same cluster `4` as you wanted. Choosing the `method="complete"` made sure that the maximum distance between all points in one cluster is what you specified with `h=10`.